# Normalization sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, normalization

Let's say i have a pandas data frame, and i want to normalize only some attributes, but not the whole data frame with the help of this function:

```
preprocessing.normalize
```

And i want to inplace these normalized columns to my data frame.But i can't because it has different format(numpy array).

I have already seen how to do the normalization other ways, for example i did like this:

```
s0 = X.iloc[:,13:15] 
X.iloc[:,13:15] = (s0 - s0.mean()) / (s0.max() - s0.min())
X.head()
```

But i really need to do it using sklearn.
Thanks, Stack!

Comment: Did you mean `s0 - s0.min()` or `s0 - s0.mean()`? The former is min/max scale, what is the latter?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is Min-max scaling. `"normalize"` in scikit has different meaning then what you want to do.

Try [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).

And most of the sklearn transformers output the numpy arrays only. For dataframe, you can simply re-assign the columns to the dataframe like below example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Now lets say you only want to min-max scale the columns A and C:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
minmax = MinMaxScaler()
df[['A', 'C']] = minmax.fit_transform(df[['A', 'C']])
```

Answer (score 1):

(s0 - s0.mean()) / (s0.max() - s0.min()) is called Mean normalization and as far as I am aware, there is no transformer in Scikit-learn to carry out this transformation.

The MinMaxScaler transforms following this formula: (s0 - **s0.min()**) / (s0.max() - s0.min())

You can do this transformation on selected variables with scikit-learn as follows:

dirty way:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler() # or any other scaler from sklearn
scaler.fit(X[[var1, var2, var20]])
X_transf[[var1, var2, var20]] = scaler.transform(X[[var1, var2, var20]])
```

better way using the ColumnTransfomer:

```
features_numerical = [var1, var2, var20]
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler())])
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('numerical', numeric_transformer, features_numerical)], remainder='passthrough'}) # to keep all other features in the data set
preprocessor.fit_transform(X)
```

The returned variable is a numpy array, so needs re-casting into pandas dataframe and addition of variable names.

More information on how to use column transformer from sklearn [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).

You need to import the ColumnTransformer and the Pipeline from sklearn, as well as the scaler of choice.